# GestureDetection: is there an equivalent to CSS hover for touch?

Tags: flutter

I have a fixed screen (no scrolling) full of a grid view of widgets, about 20 across by 100 down. I would like to

1. Have the user touch the screen
2. Drag their finger across the screen, over the multiple fixed widgets
3. Have each widget that the finger touches fire their onTap or some other event I can capture

Is there a way to achieve this using GestureDetector or another method?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `GestureDetector`, but you have to implement it yourself, for example:

```
return GridTile(
  child: Material(
    child: GestureDetector(
      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        this.images == listOfImage[index].assetName ||
                listOfStr.contains(listOfImage[index].assetName)
            ? Positioned.fill(
                child: Opacity(
                opacity: 0.7,
                child: Image.asset(
                  listOfImage[index].assetName,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ))
            : Positioned.fill(
                child: Opacity(
                opacity: 1.0,
                child: Image.asset(
                  listOfImage[index].assetName,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              )),
        this.images == listOfImage[index].assetName ||
                listOfStr.contains(listOfImage[index].assetName)
            ? Positioned(
                left: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.check_circle,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ))
            : Visibility(
                visible: false,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.check_circle_outline,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              )
      ]),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (listOfStr
              .contains(listOfImage[index].assetName)) {
            this.clicked = false;
            listOfStr.remove(listOfImage[index].assetName);
            this.images = null;
          } else {
            this.images = listOfImage[index].assetName;
            listOfStr.add(this.images);
            this.clicked = true;
          }
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Here the `GestureDetector` takes a `Stack` as a child. The `listOfImages` contains a list of `AssetImages`, that are using in the `GridView`:

```
   GridView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      itemCount: listOfImage.length,
```

The `listOfStr` contains the name of the AssetImage, `listOfImage[index].assetName`. So here the `onTap` first checks if the image is inside the `list`, if it is inside then it means the image is clicked and it has a checkmark on it and the `opacity` is equal to 0.8, therefore if you `tap` the image again it will be unselected

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the reply - I don't think this will have the required functionality. onTap fires only when the user takes their finger _off_ the screen. I'm looking to have an event fired when the touching finger _enters_ the widgets bounds.

Comment: ontap fires whenever the user is clicking on an image in the gridview, the above code is here https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-storage-in-flutter-9f23b04291e5 you can also find an image of the ontap thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Flutter `InkWell` widget to achieve a hover effect:

Check the code below for a short example of how to do it:

```
 InkWell(
        // use any color for your hover effect
        hoverColor: Colors.blue,
        // any child widget here
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
```

I hope this answers your question.